# LiveUsb - PfSense Installation on USB Key

Tags: router, usb-flash-drive, liveusb, pfsense

Is it possible to install the PfSense software into a USB key, configure it through the computer and then plug it to the router ?
Might it work?

Please give me a concrete answer or maybe another idea.
I would like to avoid either to configure an old PC or to buy the netgate hardware device (the cheapest one [$200] gives me only 74MBs with the VPN out of the 500MB that I have)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible only possible if "the router" is already either a netgate device or an old pc.

It's freebsd and source is available but given that you're asking you probably don't have the skills to successfully complile all the software and replace the OS on your existing router.